# Tiles and redirect in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, redirect, tiles

I am using Tiles 2 in my Spring 3 MVC application
i defines a form :

```
     <definition name="addcompany.htm" extends="baseLayout">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Add Company"/>
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/WEB-INF/jsp/addcompany.jsp"/>      
  </definition>
```

and :

```
addcompany.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
addcompany.url=addcompany.htm
```

And here is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addcompany.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getForm() {
    logger.info("Getting form!");
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    logger.info("Loading form");
    Company cmp = new Company();
    mav.addObject("company",cmp);
    mav.setViewName("addcompany");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/addcompany.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String  postForm(@ModelAttribute("company") Company cmp) {
    logger.info("post form!");
    companyService.saveCompany(cmp);
    logger.info("post form");
    return "redirect:tiles:companylist"; // How do i redirect?
}
```

Using Tiles2, the REDIRECT doesnt work.

Any idea how to redirect after a successful POST using Tiles ?

thanks

EDIT :
Solution is to add this in the views.properties :

```
redirectcompanylist.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView
redirectcompanylist.url=/companylist.htm
```

And return **redirectcompanylist** in the controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use the URL path when redirecting. Like this: `return redirect:/companylist.htm` which then goes to the corresponding method in the controller.

Comment: Thanks , but i get a 500 error : Could not resolve view with name 'redirect:/companylist.htm'  . companylist has its own Tile also like addcompany

Comment: Do you have a method in your controller annotated with `@RequestMapping(value="/companylist.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)`?

Comment: yes i have it. and when i go to the /companylist.htm url in my browser it works. But after i filled the form and the the company was added in the database, the redirect gives me this error : javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'redirect:/companylist.htm' in servlet

Comment: Which class have you configured as the `ViewResolver` in the application context? If it's not an instance of `UrlBasedViewResolver` it's not able to handle the `redirect:` prefix. As an alternative you could use `RedirectView` and change the return type to `View`.

Comment: here is my view resolver : <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" p:basename="views" />  . You have any exemple how to make it work with it? thanks

Comment: redirectcompanylist.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView
redirectcompanylist.url=/companylist.htm

Comment: `ResourceBundleViewResolver` doesn't extend `UrlBasedViewResolver`. I'm myself using `<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />`.